# How can I extract n elements from each m-by-m window of a matrix without using loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix and 2 parameters. The first parameter `n` is the number of elements to be selected. The second is the window size `m`.

I want to select `n` number of elements from every `m`-by-`m` window from the matrix. As a result we will have a `p`-by-`q` cell array where `p` is `matrix_height/m` and `q` is `matrix_width/m`.

Each element of the cell array contains the `n` greatest numbers from the corresponding window. It does not necessarily need to be a cell array, it can be anything that will store the necessary data.

Comment: You could look at |blockproc| http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/blockproc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is by first finding all the unique `m`-by-`m` submatrices of your matrix using the function [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html), then sorting each column in descending order using the function [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html), and finally extracting the top `n` rows. If your initial matrix is `A` and your output matrix is `B`, this is what it would look like:

```
B = sort(im2col(A,[m m],'distinct'),1,'descend');
B = B(1:n,:);  %# Get the top n values
```

Note that `B` will be an `n`-by-`m^2` matrix. If you want to turn this into a `p`-by-`q` cell array, you can do this using the functions [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html) and [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html):

```
nBlocks = ceil(size(A)./m);  %# The number of blocks in each dimension
B = reshape(num2cell(B,1),nBlocks(1),nBlocks(2));
```

**EDIT:**

If you also want to get the indices of each value with respect to the input matrix `A`, that is a bit more complicated. You can do it by getting the second output from [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html), which in this case will be the linear indices of the values within each `m`-by-`m` submatrix. You can convert these to subscripts using the function [IND2SUB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ind2sub.html), then shift the row and column indices to account for the position of each `m`-by-`m` block:

```
[B,index] = sort(im2col(A,[m m],'distinct'),1,'descend');
B = B(1:n,:);                  %# Get the top n values
index = index(1:n,:);          %# Get the top n values
[r,c] = ind2sub([m m],index);  %# Convert linear indices to subscripts
nBlocks = size(A)./m;          %# The number of blocks in each dimension
r = r+repmat(0:m:(nBlocks(1)-1)*m,n,nBlocks(2));      %# Shift the row indices
c = c+kron(0:m:(nBlocks(2)-1)*m,ones(n,nBlocks(1)));  %# Shift the column indices
```

And now you can collect the row indices, column indices, and values together into a cell array using the functions [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html) and [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html):

```
B = mat2cell([r(:) c(:) B(:)],n.*ones(1,size(B,2)));
B = reshape(B,nBlocks(1),nBlocks(2));
```

Alternatively, you can create a structure array instead of a cell array using the functions [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html), [STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html), and [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html):

```
B = struct('rowIndices',num2cell(r,1),...
           'colIndices',num2cell(c,1),...
           'values',num2cell(B,1));
B = reshape(B,nBlocks(1),nBlocks(2));
```

**NOTE:**

The function [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html) will pad partial blocks with zeroes in the event that a dimension of `A` is not an even multiple of `m`. If any of this zero-padding appears in the top `n` values for a block, one or both of the corresponding row and column indices will be out of range (i.e. have a value larger than the size of that dimension for the matrix `A`). Thus by checking that the row and column indices are in range you can make sure you are not including any of the zero-padding in your subsequent analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot gnovice... this is cool... but it will actually give the elements of the matrix from every window... what i want is that it should also give the position of those values w.r.to original matrix. 
and each window should be recognized with index p and q indices containing the matrix elements itself and also the coordinates of the elements where it is located.

Comment: Thanks again gnovice... your comment is correct... it can be changed to a p-by-q array like this... only missing thing is the row and the column number where these values are actually located in matrix A. for example cellarray(1,1) depicting the first window should result in [col_num row_mum value]... I hope that it is clear now. Shan

Comment: @Shan: It's much trickier to get the row and column indices with respect to the original matrix. It'll take more time to figure that out.

Comment: @gnovice I hope you are going to give it a try when you will find time.

Comment: @gnovice... It is also possible that we make a struct having fields row_num, col_num and value and we store n of these structs per window.

Comment: @Shan: I also added a note that you should pay particular attention to.

Comment: @gnovice thanks for the note... As the values in the matrix will always be positive so in that case nothing will happen. But it could be a problem that there are some zeros... and then what i think is that the selection will be random which i should take care of.

Comment: @gnovice I think the other solution could be that first we get total number of windows possible like (rows+m-1)/m. After that we can calculate that how many rows to spare and we evenly divide it on the both sides as boundaries and take the matrix evenly sized from inside. I think that will work. Because in image processing context we don't really pay much attention at the boundaries.